# Homeomorphism in $\mathbb{R}$ with the upper limit topology.

Tags: general-topology

Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the upper limit topology (open sets are of the form $(a,b]$) and consider the subsets $(0,1]$ and $(0, +\infty)$ with the corresponding relative topologies. Show that $(0,1]$ and $(0, +\infty)$ are homeomorphic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Each of the subspaces is homeomorphic to the Cartesian product $(0,1]\times\Bbb N$, where $\Bbb N$ has the discrete topology. Equivalently, each is the discrete union of countably infinitely many clopen copies of $(0,1]$. This is easy to see for the unbounded subspace, and

$$(0,1]=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}\left(?,\frac1n\right]\;.$$

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by "discrete union of countably infinitely clopen copies of $(0,1]$"?

Comment: @Santiago: Sorry: I accidentally left out the word *many*. *Discrete union* and *clopen* are actually redundant here. The whole thing just means that you have a space that is the union of countably infinitely many pairwise disjoint copies of $(0,1]$ with the upper limit topology, and each of these copies is both an open and a closed set in the union.

Comment: So far this is what I have: First note
$$(0,\infty)=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+} (n-1,n]$$
and
$$(0,1]=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+} \left(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\right]$$
Then define a function
$$f_n=(n-1,n] \longrightarrow \left(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\right]$$
And then use the pasting lemma.
The problem is that I have no idea how to define each function $f_n$ so that it is bicontinuous and bijective.

Comment: @Santiago: That should be $(n-1,n]$ in the first and third displayed lines, with right-closed intervals, not $(n-1,n)$ with open intervals. Having that right should make it easier. It may also help to replace $f_n$ by a composition of a homeomorphism $g_n:(n-1,n]\to(0,1]$ and a homeomorphism $g_n:(0,1]\to\left(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right]$, since those are a bit easier to write down directly.

Comment: Sorry for that mistake, I already corrected it. Also... Aren't those $g_n$'s different? I mean $g_n:(n-1,n]\rightarrow (0,1]$ and $h_n:(0,1]\rightarrow \left(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\right]$; and then make $f_n=h_n\circ g_n$.

Comment: @Santiago: Oops; wrong hand triggered. Yes, I meant the second one to be $h_n$, exactly as you have it.

Comment: @Santiago: Let’s see; $g_n$ is certainly right, but $h_n$ doesn’t quite work, because it sends $0$ to $\frac{n}{n+1}$ instead of to $\frac1{n+1}$. The length of the target interval is $\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}=\frac1{n(n+1)}$, and $\frac{x}{n(n+1)}$ goes from $0$ to $\frac1{n(n+1)}$ as $x$ goes from $0$ to $1$, so you want $$h_n(x)=\frac{x}{n(n+1)}+\;?$$

Comment: Sorry for deleting my comment, I immediately realized that $h_n$ was wrong after I added the comment. I think this is the right answer:
$$h_n(x)=\frac{x+n}{n(n+1)}$$.

Comment: @Santiago: Yes, that works fine.